# Laravel app using Jaws Maria DB on Heroku getting MYSQL errors

Tags: mysql, laravel, heroku

I have a Laravel app on Heroku using Maria DB as a Add on. My App is up and running. Everything works on my local.  When I try to run heroku php artisan migrate    to migrate my tables to DB, I am getting this error.

In Connector.php line 68:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

In Connector.php line 68:

PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

I have added my Env vars to the Heroku dashboard.  Once I added JAWS Marai DB it gave me the JAWS_MARIA_DB connection string but I have tried it with just this, I have deleted this var and added all the nexessary DB var from  my .env and nothing is working.  BTW I am using the DB values given to me from Heroku JAWS DB settings page and NOT the values from my local project.

Anyone have any idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little old, but I thought this would help others trying to diagnose this issue.

You'll want to add the following to your database config file.

```
if(getenv('SQL_URL')) {
  $url = parse_url(getenv('SQL_URL'));

  putenv('DB_HOST='.$url['host']);
  putenv('DB_PORT='.$url['port']);
  putenv('DB_USERNAME='.$url['user']);
  putenv('DB_DATABASE='.substr($url["path"], 1));
  putenv('DB_PASSWORD='.$url['pass']);
}
```

As long as you have the jawsDB URL added to your config vars in Heroku, this will parse that URL and generate the correct DB configuration information.